# VB.NET Index Of, finding word position

Tags: vb.net, string, indexof

I have a basic piece of code.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Test As String = "test example"

    Console.WriteLine(Test.IndexOf("example"))
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

The output would be "5" as the position of the start of the specified string is 5. I would still like to use indexof but how can i make it find the word location of the specified string such as it would output "2" as the word location is the 2nd word.

Comment: You first need to know what separates words. Dot, comma, semi-colon, tabs, apostrophe, space?

Comment: Word, or a chunk of non-whitespace chars? Split with spaces and find the index of the chunk equal to your "word".

Comment: What if it's only a substring of a word? Not very clear. Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>[`Array.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx)</kbd> method

```
Dim str As [String] = "First Second Third Forth"
Dim arr As String() = str.Split(" "C)
Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(arr, "Second") + 1)
```

Comment: What does this mean? str.Split(" "C) And whats is the C for?

Comment: As name suggest split function split string in parts and `C` is to denote char data type

Comment: Awesome :D thanks. I had looped my previous code for multiple instances so I could find multiple words in the string. How could I loop this version you have given me?